# How to use module inside another module with extend ActiveSupport::Concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I've got this, and i want to use **number_front** method inside **Base::Helper** in **Report::Toyota**, it's giving me an error: `undefined method number_front`

```
module Base
  module Helper
    def number_front(member)
      "***#{member}"
    end
  end
end

module Report
  module Toyota
    extend Base::Helper # not sure here, what's the right way to include it
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      comma do
        model(mark: 'Toyota') { |number| number_front(number) if number }
      end
    end
  end
end

class Car
  include Report::Toyota
end
```

Comment: Why isn't `Base::Helper` a concern too?

Comment: i don't want to make them concern, as there're bunch of them and there're written by others as simple modules

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
extend Base::Helper
```

use

```
include Base::Helper
```

The difference is that `include` will add the method as an instance method.